# Setting default database for MongoDB shell

Tags: shell, mongodb, terminal

When I go into the mongo shell in my terminal, it always starts with the database test, which is the wrong database. Can you set mongo to start in a specific database?

Comment: use this to add default database in connection string: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22418052/connect-to-a-specific-database-by-default-in-mongodb/67114084#67114084

Answer (score 54, accepted):

#### Command Line

You can select the database to use on the [mongo command line](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Overview+-+The+MongoDB+Interactive+Shell#Overview-TheMongoDBInteractiveShell-RunningtheShell), eg for 'mydb':

```
mongo mydb
```

If a database name is not provided, 'test' will be used.

#### In .mongorc.js

If you want to set a default database without specifying on the command line each time, you can add a line to the [`.mongorc.js`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongo/#mongo-mongorc-file) file in your home directory:

```
db = db.getSiblingDB("mydb")
```

The `.mongorc.js` file is executed after the `mongo` shell is started, so if you set a default here it will override a database specified on the command line.

Comment: I meant like setting a default database to use, so I wouldn't have to start up in test each time. I've set an alias in my .bash_profil now though.

Comment: I didn't realize the impact of .mongorc.js. Be careful when using .mongorc.js because when you connect to other database, like your production ones, it will still run the same commands.

Comment: @kirk: FYI, you can run `mongo --norc` if you don't want `.mongorc.js` to be run when the shell starts.

Comment: -1, if you don't have permissions to access database `test` then you are kicked out on authentication before `.mongorc.js` kicks in.

Comment: If you are using mongosh, edit .mongoshrc.js instead.

Answer (score 5):

It's entirely possible to set a default, albiet in a slightly strange way. Here's what I do for using automatic authentication to an admin in .mongorc.js:

```
// Persist the database selected
var selectedDB = db

// Authenticate
db = db.getSiblingDB("admin")
db.auth('admin','adminpass')

// Switch back to selected DB
db = selectedDB

// Universally allow read queries on secondaries from shell. 
rs.slaveOk()
```

To directly answer the question, I'd think the way to accomplish this is simply by executing a check to see if the current database loaded up is "test" and alter only if that's the case, so.

```
if (db.name == 'test')
  db.getSiblingDB('yourdefaultdb')
```

This allows both selecting a database at the command line and setting a default. Naturally it'll prevent you from overriding and using the "test" db from the command line, but I think that's a bit of a strange use case given the question. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

At the moment (looking 2.6.4) there is no way to universally set the default DB for the client. It seems hardcoded to `test`. In my anger I downvoted the Stennie's answer [1] because it doesn't work if your user does not have permissions to access the test database. But if your case is not such, then it may work good enough.

[1] and I can't reverse my vote now unless answer is edited

Comment: Where is the 'test' db as the default database hard coded ? i tried **db = db.getSiblingDB("mydb")** in the root/.mongorc.js but not working

Comment: @Crazyrubixfan Apparently it is right in the mongo shell executable itself: `strings /usr/bin/mongo | grep 'dbName || "test"'` shows multiple instances.