# Connect to a specific database by default in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongo-shell

I am running a mongodb on a linux box. So every time I connect to it from the console (typing `mongo`) I get something like this:

```
MongoDB shell version: 2.4.9
connecting to: test
```

And then I am doing use `myDatabase` (where myDatabase is 99% is the same). So basically I always do some unneeded type of work. Is there a way to configure mongo, so that it will connect to `myDatabase` by default?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Setting default database for MongoDB shell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11336346/setting-default-database-for-mongodb-shell)

Comment: Wow, sorry for duplicate...

Comment: @WiredPrairie and it is. Searched for the wrong thing

Answer (score 17):

Surprised that I don't find a duplicate of this. Okay, now we have content.

From the command line, just do this:

> $ mongo myDatabase

This actually is covered in the [documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongo/#bin.mongo), albeit down the page somewhat. No direct link but search for `<db address>` and the same example is there.

Of course you could have done:

```
$ mongo --help
MongoDB shell version: 2.4.9
usage: mongo [options] [db address] [file names (ending in .js)]
db address can be:
    foo                   foo database on local machine
    192.169.0.5/foo       foo database on 192.168.0.5 machine
    192.169.0.5:9999/foo  foo database on 192.168.0.5 machine on port 9999
```

Which shows the usage along with other options you can pass in.

Another thing, not quite a default connect but a shortcut is you can do this in the `.mongorc.js` file:

```
db=db.getSiblingDB("myDatabase")
```

Which assigns the variable `db` to that database so now:

```
db.collection.find()
```

Is acting on `myDatabase`.

Comment: Thanks, but I knew about mongo myDatabase, but for me this is actually  the same thing: as I still need to type the name of my database. Sorry that I have not written about it in my question.

Comment: @SalvadorDali Okay then, more info in the edit that should suit.

Answer (score 3):

As per latest mongodb drivers, we can provide default `database` name in connection string like this:

**1.** **Connect using the mongoShell**

```
mongo "mongodb+srv://sandbox.ununu.mongodb.net/mydatabase" --username user001
```

**2. Connect using the drivers**

`mongodb+srv://user001:<password>@sandbox.ununu.mongodb.net/mydatabase?retryWrites=true&w=majority`

**Details of parametere:**

- Replace mydatabase with the name of the database that connections will use by default.
- `sandbox.ununu.mongodb.net` is your cluster name
- You will be prompted for the password for the Database User,user001.
- `user001` is username

For more details on passing ReplicaSet, other query string parameters, etc. refer mongodb official document. [document link](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/)

Answer (score 0):

Usually mongodb connects to default database `test`. It's very simple connect to any database, we just need to specify the new `database name` in the mongo shell

1. With authentication enabled and enter password on runtime (preferred mostly)

   ```
   mongo --port 27017 -u USERNAME DATABASE_NAME --authenticationDatabase admin
   ```
2. With authentication enabled and password supplied on shell (not recommended)

   ```
   mongo --port 27017 -u USERNAME -p PASSWORD DATABASE_NAME --authenticationDatabase admin
   ```
3. With authentication disabled

   ```
   mongo --port 27017 -u USERNAME -p PASSWORD DATABASE_NAME
   ```

The above commands will directly connect to the database which we have specified.

**Note:** make sure the user has the necessary privilege to perform the operations

Answer (score 0):

```
mongosh
use admin
db.createUser({ user: "user" , pwd: "1234", roles: [ "readWrite", "dbAdmin" ] })

use metadata
db.createCollection("product")

// mongodb://user:1234@localhost:27017/metadata
```